# Blazor - <NavigationLock ConfirmExternalNavigation is not reading the latest property value

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

In my razor file I have:

```
<NavigationLock ConfirmExternalNavigation="@HasUnsavedChanges" OnBeforeInternalNavigation="OnBeforeInternalNavigation" />
```

And then in my HandleValidSubmitAsync I call (the true is needed because it's going to one of the Identity MVC pages):

```
HasUnsavedChanges = false;
StateHasChanged();
await Task.Delay(100);
Navigation.NavigateTo(gotoUrl, true);
```

Without the `StateHasChanged()` and the `await Task.Delay(100)`, I get the browser popup. I'm fine with the call to `StateHasChanged()` but the call to `Task.Delay(100)` is a hack that is asking for trouble.

Any ideas on how to avoid this? The best I came up with (haven't tried it because I'm hoping for something better here) is instead of calling `NavigateTo()`, I set another bool to true and then in `OnParametersSet()`, if that bool is true, do the navigation there.

Is there a better/cleaner approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code looked like this:

```cs
HasUnsavedChanges = false;
StateHasChanged();
await Task.Yield();
// This component and NavigationLock sub-component get rendered 
Navigation.NavigateTo(gotoUrl, true);
```

Then you would probably not consider the `await Task.Yield();` a hack.  What it's effectively doing is creating a continuation where the code after the yield get's kicked down the road and any scheduled code gets run before it.

That's exactly what you want.  You have called `StateHasChanged` to add a component render to the queue, but unless you yield, that render won't happen until after the block of code completes.

And that's important in this instance because the render event on the component triggers a render on the `NavigationLock` component.  As `HasUnsavedChanges` is now false, when the component renders it removes the JS `beforeunload` handler.

Without the render the JS `beforeunload` handler is still registered and triggers the popup.

Several authors suggest using `Task.Delay(1)` instead of `Task.Yield()` because they believe `Yield` doesn't always work.  I'm not of that school until someone with the *knowledge* from MS educates me otherwise, so use `Yield`.  @HH is of the other school, and will no doubt chip in!

You can review how `NavigationLock` works here - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Web/src/Routing/NavigationLock.cs.

Comment: Back in the day in Windows programming we would have to do Sleep(0) at times. Never liked it but it was a way to have every other thread get a slice of processing time. I trust your judgement and will go with the Yield() call.

Comment: Welcome to the async world.  Blazor is inherently async, so get used to thinking async.  With almost every method I now think `async` or not.  Will I need to upgrade this to async later, if so async now?  Also get to know the differences between a `ValueTask` and a `Task`: most of my async methods use `ValueTask`.

Comment: Async I've got lots of experience with. But in the Windows app world I would use PostMessage() a lot because that would then fire after all items presently in the queue fired. It's the "happens whenever" with no way to say I need Y to happen after X that I dislike. But if programming was easy they wouldn't have to pay us so much :)